# How to modify the description of products in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have a simple plugin in magento 2 that modifies the name of the products, but I can not find the function that modifies the description

```
public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
{
   return '|' . $result . ' - Test';
}
```

So modified the names of the products, I also have the function to modify the prices but what is the function to modify the description?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public function afterLoad(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $subject->setData('description', $subject->getDescription() . '-Test Description');
        return $result;
    }
```

Let me know your result

Regards

Comment: Brother works, but may not explain what I need, I want the changes to be seen in the description that appears just below the price when a product is selected

Comment: The content brother is what I want to be able to modify, which is below the price